What distribution does the height of both men and women follow?
It is often said that the height of men and that of women follow normal distribution with different means and variances. As graphs suggest, it appears true.
Then, what is the whole distribution of both men and women? Is it normal distribution or other distribution?
(I'm asking a distribution the height of randomly chosen people follow, including both men and women.)
I thought it is related to the reproductive property of the normal distribution, but it appears slightly different.

That would be an example of a mixture distribution. And the mixture of two normals is not necessarily normal (in fact it is almost never normal). Also, the idea that men and women's heights follow normal distributions is obviously an idealization. At the very least, any normal distribution can produce negative values; and that is nonsense for heights.
Anyway, even if you model the heights of men and women as normal variables say $M, W \in \mathbb{R}$ distributed as $\sim N(\mu_M, \sigma_M^2), N(\mu_W, \sigma_W^2)$ the distribution of people in general, say $P \in \mathbb{R}$, would be a mixture of $M, W$ for e.g. if men and women are equally numerous, $P$ would be $M$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ while $W$ with the probability $1 - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$ too. This means the density of $P$ is
$$
f_P(x) = \frac{1}{2} f_M(x) + \frac{1}{2}f_W(x) =  \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sigma_W\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma_W^2}(x - \mu_W)^2} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\sigma_M\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma_M^2}(x - \mu_M)^2}
$$ which can't be expressed as a normal density unless very special conditions are met for e.g. the heights of men and women have same mean $\mu_M = \mu_W$ and deviation $\sigma_M = \sigma_W$.
